# AVFoundation upload HD video

Tags: iphone, upload, avfoundation

I am using AVFoundation to record video and upload it to a server. Currently I am using a resolution of 640x480 and the size of the file is good enough to send over the net.
When I switch to HD (1280x720), the size of the file is getting significantly bigger and it becomes too big to transfer on the network.

Is there a way of dramatically reducing HD files before uploading and still maintaining a decent quality?

Comment: Can you please share some code about how to upload video using AVFoundation? 640X480 res is fine for my app.  I was going to ask this question, but I see that you've already achieved it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kwame, sorry to disappoint you, I didn't achieve it. I stayed with 640x480 which is much small. I couldn't find a code on the net for compressing the 1280x720.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way of dramatically reducing HD files before uploading and still maintaining a decent quality?

That would be the holy grail of video compression :) You can use [`AVAssetExportSession`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios//#/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to change the compression settings and video resolution, but that’t about it.

Comment: Thanks Zoul, I know about this class. I want to keep the same HD resolution and only to compress the video to the max in order to make it easier to transfer on the internet. When I used this class the compression was not significant. Is there some example showing the best combination or parameters?